# EJB3 Singleton with HashMap vs JPA 2nd Level @Cacheable on Entity

Tags: jpa, singleton, entity, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to determine which methodology for caching is better using an EJB3 Singleton session bean with HashMap or using 2nd level Caching with @Cacheable annotation on Entity.

Comment: This might be dependent on your case. Questions like "which one is better" are dependent on what goal must be reached. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by singleton SessionBean, but it doesn't sound good.  Use @Cacheable.

Comment: Hi James, you can use an EJB3 Singleton session bean and add a HashMap as cache, and the container-concurrency-management will handle synchronization. So essentially, by adding a HashMap in a Singleton, it becomes like a 2nd level cache.  So to my question, do I really need to do @Cacheable at the entity level in JPA to have a 2nd level cache or simply just use a HashMap as cache in the Singleton session bean.  Thanks